# Batch file to covert unicode text to Ansi text

Tags: batch-file

How can I convert a directory of pre-existing text from Unicode to ANSI with a batch file?  Is there some tool that I can use to loop through the files and perform the conversion?

Comment: Unicode... do you mean UTF-8?  Or something else?

Answer (score 5):

See https://superuser.com/questions/27060/batch-convert-files-for-encoding-or-line-ending.  Specifically, iconv looks exactly like what you're looking for.

You're looking for the reverse of the example posted there, so you'd want something like this:

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 5):

*EDIT - The following will convert UTF-16 with BOM. I don't think it works with any of the other UTF formats. I know it doesn't work for UTF-8. I'm not sure about UTF-32 with BOM*

```
for %%F in (*.txt) do type "%%F" >"%%~nF.converted"
```

If run from the command line then use single percent `%` instead of double percent `%%`.

After you verify the converted files are correct, you can

```
del *.txt
ren *.converted *.txt
```

Comment: Beware that this uses DOS encoding.

Comment: @Vadzim - DOS (the OS) is virtually non-existent now, The Windows command line and batch is ***not*** DOS. And there is no such thing as DOS encoding. DOS (and Windows command line) support many different code pages, each with its own encoding. I understand what you meant, but that was the entire point of the question in the first place.

Comment: I mean that in case of OS in Russian locale the result would appear in CP866 instead of CP1251 that most would really need.