# Convert Unicode file to ANSI using Bat file

Tags: batch-file, unicode, ansi, essbase

I need to convert a unicode text file (19,000K) to an ANSI text file for use with Essbase.

I currently have this written to convert the file but only the first 7800 lines are copying.

**This is what I have in my .bat file**

cmd /a /c TYPE PVTBHFM_20160708.dat > PVTBHFM_ANSI.dat

What am I missing to fully convert this file?

Is there a way to save the file in a different location?

Comment: This is nitpicking, but you probably mean [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). "ANSI" isn't a character encoding. Windows mislabels Windows-1252 text as ANSI a lot.

Comment: @yellowantphil - http://i.imgur.com/qs70fxu.png Perfectly reasonable for him to think it's called ANSI.

Comment: @yellowantphil nope. [1252 (Latin I)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654) is merely a **particular** Windows code page (or _character encoding_ as you say). "ANSI"  is a Microsoft's alias (moniker) for _**current** system Windows code page_;  for instance, my one is _[1250 (Central Europe)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250)_. Sure, all this spoonerism comes from Microsoft's large-scaled terminology approach…

Comment: @JosefZ I guess I should have said Windows-125[0-8], or whatever the possibilities are.

Comment: How many _lines_ in the original file when only `7800` lines are copied? And how many _bytes_  in the target file? Should be (cca `±1`) a half of `19,000K`

Comment: @josefZ there's 23,000 lines, the output file only has 7800 lines. Target size is usually 9,700 kb after converting to ANSI, which apparently is called a bunch of other things /Windows-1252

Comment: So target size is approx. `1/2` of source? Then, convert seems to be successful? Maybe there is (one or more) `^Z` i.e. `Ctrl`+`Z` i.e. _Substitute_ character (codepoint `U+001A`, ASCII code `26` decimal) in your data. Check difference between `type PVTBHFM_ANSI.dat` and `findstr /N "^" PVTBHFM_ANSI.dat` from an open `cmd` window. `type` would end on 7800th line while `findstr` does not care about `^Z` character interpretation and should  display _all_ lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch file to covert unicode text to Ansi text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781367/batch-file-to-covert-unicode-text-to-ansi-text)